# React is rendering [Object object] instead of JSX elements inside the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this array of buttons in my React application:

```
const buttons = [    
<Button label='Close' onClick={props.handleClose} />,
<Button label='Save' onClick={props.handleSubmit} />,
<Button label='Reset' onClick={props.handleReset} />
]
```

But when I render them:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='buttons'>{buttons.join()}</div>
    )
}
```

I get:

```
 Object object Object object Object object
```

And I want to get those elements.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use `.join()`. It's enough to just pass an array like that:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='buttons'>{buttons}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why need to use `join`. There is no need.

```
const buttons = [    
<Button label='Close' onClick={props.handleClose} />,
<Button label='Save' onClick={props.handleSubmit} />,
<Button label='Reset' onClick={props.handleReset} />
]
render() {
    return (
        <div className='buttons'>{buttons}</div>
    )
}
```